# Maintaining consistent visual fill column under `org-indent-mode`

Tags: org-mode, indentation, fill-column

How can one enable `org-indent-mode` (or otherwise indent content to Org headings) while still maintaining a consistent visual fill column?

[image]

Comment: Does this still happen?  I tried replicating this in 2022 with org-mode + org-indent-mode + visual-fill-column-mode, and I didn't see the undesired overflow.

Comment: @g-gundam This happens for me in Org 9.5.5 on Emacs 28.1.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this behavior is to disable `org-indent-mode` and set `org-adapt-indentation` to `t`. The side effect of this configuration is that spaces will be added to Org file, where `org-indent-mode` only acts at render time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to do this is by overriding the function that returns the fill column.

```lisp
(defun current-fill-column ()
      "Return the fill-column to use for this line.
Subtracts right margin and org indentation level from fill-column"
      (let ((indent-level (if (bound-and-true-p org-indent-mode)
                              (* org-indent-indentation-per-level
                                 (org-current-level))
                            0))
            (margin (or (get-text-property (point) 'right-margin) 0)))
        (- fill-column indent-level margin)))
```

This probably misses some edge cases, since the original function is more complex, but this is working for my purposes so far.